# Section numbering missing in classicthesis

Tags: sectioning, numbering, classicthesis

I am trying to write my master thesis using `classicthesis` package, everything if working fine except the `section` numbering.

I am able to start the chapters correctly.[image: chapter starting image]

But when I start a section I have the issue. I want to have a section numbering also. It comes in the top of the page, but I also want it in the beginning of the section.[image: section starting image]

Would also like to have the page number to the bottom of the page. The big number when the chapter starts is okay. But in the other pages I want to have it to the bottom of the page not on the top right cornet, instead in the bottom left corner,

Comment: Have you tried to compile the original template, as downloaded from bitbucket? Chapters, sections and subsections should all be numbered by default. You must have changed something, haven't you? For the pagenumbers, try this `\lehead{\mbox{\headmark\hfil}}
\rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\headmark}}}
\lefoot{\mbox{\llap{\small\pagemark}}}
\rofoot{\mbox{\rlap{\small\pagemark}}}`

Answer (score 7):

After hours of searching I figured out what is the issue.

Its because of a bug in the `titlesec` package.
Get the latest package from [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec) and replace the contents of `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec`

After replacing it, the section numbering would be back.